# Google is showing my old URL, how to remove that from google index and add my new URL in google index?

Tags: php, python, html, css, web

Recently I have made changes to my URL I have changed http://letsfindcourse.com/machine_learning to this http://letsfindcourse.com/machine-learning but google is showing my old url in google search. I have already submitted new sitemap to google 2 days back. But still it is showing old url. Can someone help me how to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

It may take some time for links to be updated in search results. Meanwhile what you should do is, set up redirects to avoid 404.

Comment: How much time it will take and do it remove the old links for google index

Comment: @Divesh submitting your sitemap to google search console can help speed up that process.

Comment: @Divesh have to wait till google crawler visits your site. If you found this answer helpful, please mark this as answer

Comment: does google remove my old URL automatically from index